# How to place a button beside a select List

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, html.dropdownlistfor, selectlist, asp.net-mvc-views

I am coding an MVC 5 view, and I want to place a button next to a select list. My current code places the button under the select list.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.userName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.userName, Model.userNames, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Select" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is an image showing the button placement:

[image: Button placement]

Even if I have the following code, the button is under the select list:

```
<p>
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.userName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.userName, Model.userNames, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" }) <input type="submit" value="Select" class="btn btn-default" />
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't put the submit button in a div.

A div is `display: block` by default.

Comment: `col-md-offset-2` is bootstrap. Without looking it up, I think it's `float:left`

Comment: Even if I remove all the divs, the button is still under the select list.

Comment: @Rhumborl — That wouldn't stop it from generating a new line. Float lets following stuff bubble up beside.

Comment: @user3736648 — Then there is insufficient code in your question to tell what the problem is. By default, if you have a `<select>` and an `<input>` as siblings, they will render next to each other (word wrap not withstanding).

Comment: Is there a style line of code that I can add to the div or each of the html objects that will force the alignment?

Comment: You need to determine why the alignment is wrong first. Try using the CSS part of the developer tools built into your browser to figure out what the cause is.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="input-group">
   @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.userName, Model.userNames, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
   <span class="input-group-btn">
   <input type="submit" value="Select" class="input-group-addon btn btn-default" />
   </span>
</div>
```

By using the classes input-group on the div, input-group-btn on the span and input-group-addon on the select button , you can place dropdownlist and button on the same line.

Refer to this article :
https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/twitter-bootstrap-tutorial/bootstrap-input-groups.php